# Are there SQL performance benefits to using a linked server vs openquery?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-administration, linked-server, openquery

I've done some digging and don't have a clear-cut answer.

We have a server that handles roughly 90% of all requests and another 20 servers (or so) that handle the final 10%. Most of our SSRS requests ping this server.

We're constantly pinging an Oracle server using `OPENQUERY` as well, so I'm wondering: aside from spinning off another server, would we benefit from using `OPENQUERY` more often than `LINKEDSERVER` where possible? I realize that referencing temp tables in the query wouldn't work, but if it's a straight pull, no `WHERE` clause, would the main server see a performance boost? TIA

Comment: What do you mean with "using `OPENQUERY` more often than `LINKEDSERVER`"?

Comment: Performance is normally the same. The only benefit of `OPENQUERY` is that it allows you to enforce which part of the query is executed locally and which part remotely

Comment: Thanks @Charlieface.

Comment: @JaimeDrq you can direct query many legacy linked servers, as long as they are 32-bit machines. `OPENQUERY` is a must command for 64-bit.